Can RabbitMQ be used in a Python program which is both a Publisher and a Subscriber?
I am developing an app which has, at its center, a .NET REST api that handles requests and submits tasks to a queue, which is being listened to by Python workers that do the heavy maths.
My problem is: How can I notify the REST that a task has been processed successfully, without http calls? I was thinking about publishing a "done" message from my Python workers in a different queue, which the REST would listen to, but since the channel.basic_consume() is a blocking operation in Python, I don't know if it is also possible to use my Python workers as publishers.
Could it be a solution to use 2 different threads in Python, one for consuming tasks and one for publishing messages?
Thanks.
